# How to filter a Seq in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a question, I have a Scala Seq of Fruit Objects, where the name member  variable of the object is the name of the fruit like

```
fruits: Seq[Fruit] = List(banana, apple, jackfruit, pineapple, grapes, watermelon, papaya, orange, pomegranate, strawberry)
```

and I have a scala String which contains the name of the fruit separated by comma like

```
val ilike = "apple, grapes, watermelon, guava"
```

I need to filter the above Seq such that it contain only the objects of Fruit I like, that is the result should be,

```
fruits: Seq[Fruit] = List(apple, grapes, watermelon)
```

I tried the Java way, but I am interested how to work the same in the Scala way. I googled a bit but I couldn't find the correct answer.

Thank You for your help in advance.

Comment: If you think that the answer is correct you should accept it by clicking on check sign. Welcome to StackOverFlow!

Comment: Can you describe your Fruit class? Does it have any property which can be equal to one of "apple, grapes, watermelon, guava" ?

Comment: Fruit class has a member variable name where name holds the name of the fruit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An even more succinct way - use `intersect`

```
scala> val like = ilike.split(", ")
like: Array[String] = Array(pineapple, grapes, watermelon, guava)

scala> fruits.intersect(like)
res1: Seq[String] = List(pineapple, grapes, watermelon)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just using `ilike.contains` as the filter function fails if `ilike` contains a name whose substring is in `fruit`:

```
scala> val ilike = "pineapple, grapes, watermelon, guava"
ilike: String = pineapple, grapes, watermelon, guava

scala> fruits.filter(ilike.contains)
res1: Seq[String] = List(apple, pineapple, grapes, watermelon)
```

Therefore, `ilike` should first be split into a sequence of preferences:

```
scala> val like = ilike.split(", ")
like: Array[String] = Array(pineapple, grapes, watermelon, guava)
```

Now it's safe to use `like.contains` for filtering:

```
scala> fruits.filter(like.contains)
res3: Seq[String] = List(pineapple, grapes, watermelon)
```

Edit:
If fruits contains a list of `Fruit` instances with a `name` member, just use

```
scala> fruits.filter(f => like.contains(f.name)
res3: Seq[Fruit] = List(pineapple, grapes, watermelon)
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple:

```
  fruits.filter(f=>ilike.split(",").contains(f.name))
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I had edited the question can you re-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can this be the correct answer, considering
 1. the val ilike can be empty. If it is empty the return Seq should be fruits.
 2. the val ilike can be seperated by a comma or a comma and space.

```
if(ilike != "") {
  val like = for(i <- ilike.split(",")) yield i.trim
  fruits.filter(f => like.contains(f.name))
} else {
  fruits
}
```